# Trouble with SourceCookifier 64-bit compile on Win10

Tags: c#, notepad++

I'm trying to compile [SourceCookifier](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) for Notepad++ 64-bit on Windows 10 with VS2017.  I made a few updates to the .sln and DllExport\NppPlugin.DllExport.targets file so it actually compiles and give me a .dll file with no warnings or errors.  However, when I put that file in the Notepad++ plugins directory (in a SourceCookifier subdir) and open N++, I get a message box:

---

A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
SourceCookifier.dll is not compatible with the current version of Notepad++.
Do you want to remove this plugin from the plugins directory to prevent this message from the next launch?

YES | NO

---

More troubling, if I try the compile on Win7, it produces a DLL that actually works on my Win7 machine.  But moving that DLL to my Win10 machines results in the same error on the Win10 machine.

Has anyone compiled SourceCookifier for 64-bit and have it running on Win10?

I don't know C# at all which is complicating this for me.

Cheers.

Comment: Is your version of Notepad++ latest for Win10?  Also make sure all the intermediate dll in SourceCookifier (in the bin colder) compiled by checking the DataTime using Windows Explorer.

Comment: @jdweng: Yes, thanks.  I'm using Notepad++ 7.7.1 64-bit on Win10 - all my other plugins including some self-written / compiled ones work fine.  I started with cloning the SourceForge repo and a clean director structure so the 'msbuild' compiles everything up-to-date.

Comment: Did you check your library paths? See : https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17322/help-to-porting-sourcecookifier-for-64bit

Comment: @jdweng:  Thanks, the link you referred to (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17322/help-to-porting-sourcecookifier-for-64bit) was what spawned this request.  You'll see my attempts on that post are summarized in this question here :-)

Comment: You are still having issues after 5 months?  I had unicode issues with VS 2013.  Microsoft changed the default encoding in 2013 from UTF8 to Unicode.  Then I had a lot of issues forcing VS2013 back to UTF8.  I had some older DLL that need UTF8.  Do you know what Ansi plug-in it uses?  You can check the bin folder for the project to see the dlls in the folder.

Comment: Here is an interesting link : https://windowsreport.com/loadlibrary-failed-error-1114/

Comment: Looked at the link, I have an Intel graphics card - not NVIDIA or AMD which the article seems to point to.  Googling for Intel turned up https://www.thewindowsclub.com/loadlibrary-failed-error-1114 which I was already set to so don't think that's the culprit.

Comment: Did you check Last Window Error  and Event Viewer for errors?